# Having trouble adjusting my regular expression for this pattern

Tags: java, regex

My pattern looks as follow:

```
[number between 0-23]([delimiter][number between 0-23])+
```

The delimiter can be: `/` or `/*`.

Look that what in round brackets can repeat multiple times.

for example:

```
8/12
3/*13
9/10/12
9/*10/11
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Regext_PlayerMove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parse("12/14"));
        System.out.println(parse("14/4"));
        System.out.println(parse("5/*7"));
        System.out.println(parse("0/*7"));
        System.out.println(parse("0/*7/9"));
        System.out.println(parse("0/*7/*11"));

        // Illegal data
        System.out.println(parse("5/*77"));
        System.out.println(parse("2/4/"));
        System.out.println(parse("/1/*16/"));
        System.out.println(parse("35/7"));

    }

    private static String parse(String path) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])(\\/\\*|\\/)(1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(path);

        if (m.find()) {
            return m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

It's working fine as long as I have only single repetition (e.g: 12/14)

Can someone help me to understand how to expand my solution to capture multiple repetitions?

Comment: What result do you expect for your inputs? Should result for `9/10/12` be `91012`? If that is true, I don't think this is good approach because `1/12/11` and `11/2/11` will create same result which (depending on what you are doing with this output) could cause many problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` to repeat the previous token one or more times.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])(?:(/\\*?)(1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]))+$");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uP1oU9/4)

It's hard to capture each of them into separate groups, but you could use `matches` method for checking true or false.

Comment: Thanks! it's working perfectly.

What if I would like to get a results that contains only the numeric values, e.g: "5/*12/14" --> {5,12,24}

Comment: @Shvalb return array of strings split at `/` or `/*` like `return path.split("/\\*?");`. Don't forget to change return type form `String` to `String[]`.